# How to get the data URL from an existing image using Greasmonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, greasemonkey

There is a web page that contains an image that changes every time the page is loaded. Is there a way to extract the data URL from this image using Greasemonkey? Regular JS injected in the page doesn't work, I assume because the image is on another domain (once the image is copied onto the canvas, the canvas is considered "tainted" so method like `toDataURL()` are forbidden).

Is there some magic in Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey / Violentmonkey for this?

Comment: You need to link to the page or provide the specific details required to duplicate the situation.

Comment: The page in which the GM script is injected is private (behind a login form). The only bit that matters is that the page is on one domain and it loads an image like this: `<img id="pic" src="http://otherdomain.tld/rand.php?format=png" />` and I want to get the `.toDataURL()` of that image. This is just rephrasing what I said earlier, there's nothing else to say.